# Automatically fetch date from string in JavaScript and return same string with formatted Date

Tags: javascript

I'm having input string like -

Hi, I'll reach on 17 Dec 2019

Its basically -

[some words] + [date in any format] + [any other words optional]

Will be whatever user enters.

My requirement is to fetch the date form the given string and format it and store it with same string. So the result would be like -

[some words] + [date in my format] + [any other words optional]

Would this be possible in JavaScript (without nodejs) as Im running this on browser directly.

Tried new Date(fullString) and I get the date but loose the other parts of the string

var input = "Hi, I'll reach on 17/12/2019. Please wait."
var userDate = new Date(input);

Expected - "Hi, I'll reach on Dec 17, 2019. Please wait."

Comment: `[date in any format]` is just to unspecific. You need to _define_ what you consider valid formats upfront, so that you can write patterns to extract them from the string. And then you will have to split those into their individual parts (resp., somehow identify which part is which), because you can not feed just any arbitrary date format to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: Ok. Lets say I've date like 12/17/2018. This format as input. My main objective to know how to split the string so that I get the date and format it the way I want and then append it back to the original string. Example - https://jsfiddle.net/nrj8behf/1/

Comment: Write a regular expression to match that format, and then use a callback function to replace that matched part with the formatted date …

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toDateString()` along with `split()` or `slice()` to get desired output.

Comment: Seems like you already got the solution and it looks better than what I suggested. https://jsfiddle.net/4qLnchf0/